# How to perform Logout operation in Hyperledger Fabric GO?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ca

I am working on a basic user **Register/Login/Logout** flow using Hyperledger Fabric Go SDK. I have successfully created the signing identity using CA Client Register method and also Enroll the user.

**Register:**

```
_, err := s.CaClient.Register(&caMsp.RegistrationRequest{
    Name:           email,
    Secret:         password,
    Type:           "user",
    MaxEnrollments: -1,
    Affiliation:    "org1",
    Attributes: []caMsp.Attribute{
        {
            Name:   "usermode",
            Value:   userType,
            ECert:   true,
        },
    },
    CAName: s.CaID,
})
```

**Login:**

```
err := s.CaClient.Enroll(email, caMsp.WithSecret(password))
if err != nil {
   return  nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to enroll identity '%s': %v", email, err)
}
```

But not able to find a way to perform **Logout** flow in my web application. There are few methods i saw in Fabric CA like **RemoveIdentity and Revoke**, these are remove the user completely from the CA.

So, please suggest some technique to for my issue.

Comment: There is no logout because there is no session concept. When you enroll user, you get its certificates/private key/public key. You don't log in. With these "credentials" you can connect to a peer(s), perform operation and then disconnect from the peer.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, so, just wondering how to disconnect from the peer?

Comment: Not sure for the go SDK. But reading this https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go you have something like ``fabsdk.Close() to release resources and caches.``

Comment: great, I'll check Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no logout because there is no session concept. When you enroll user, you get its certificates/private key/public key. You don't log in. With these "credentials" you can connect to a peer(s), perform operation and then disconnect from the peer.

I do not use the go SDK, but based on [the documentation](http://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go) you could use something like `fabsdk.Close() to release resources and caches`